# Проблема в написании библиотеки для Arduino

Tags: классы, библиотеки, arduino

Доброго времени суток!

Микроконтроллер `Atmega 328p` на плате `arduino`. Среда разработки `AtmelStudio 7`. Создаю скетч для `arduino` посредством расширения `Arduino IDE for AtmelStudio 7`.

Пишу протокол для работы по com-порту. Проблема заключается в следующем: При вынесении протокола в отдельную библиотеку (*.h и *.cpp) функции класса перестают выполняться контроллером.

Конкретнее:

- Компиляция успешно проходит;
- Отладочные куски кода вставленные в функции сразу после объявления не выполняются.

В качестве тестовых блоков использовал вывод сигналов на ножки МК (вида `DDRB &=B11011111`). Наблюдение осциллографом даёт полное отсутствие сигналов на ножках МК. Таким образом прихожу к выводу что функции просто не запускаются.

В чём могут быть проблемы? Необходимо ли привести полный код проета?

Comment: А как вы подключаете эти два файла назад? Или вы h подключаете а cpp нет?

Comment: Именно, объявляю в головном файле `#include "protocol.h"`. Вообще базовые файлы и структура сгенерированы посредством самой среды разработки.